I keep getting "Uncaught TypeError: d3.create is not a function" when I imported locally installed D3js
I am building a library and I am using D3 in the library as a dependency and I want to use and install D3 locally into the library, and I also want to bundle the minimal version of D3 together with the app, but my issue is I keep getting Uncaught TypeError: d3.create is not a function error when I tried to import the create method and other methods into my project, I downloaded the d3.js and d3.min.js UMD modules and I also tried to install it via npm into a different directory outside of the project and copy the d3 folder into the project and include it from the newly copied d3 directory I still got the same error,
and when I installed it directly into the with npm i and I imported it into my project I got "Uncaught TypeError: The specifier “d3” was a bare specifier, but was not remapped to anything. Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”." error
I don't know what else to do again, I could dynamically load into the DOM through the CDN with the script tag but I want my library to be able to be loaded and used when users are not connected to the internet in development
The project environment is in TypeScript.
How do I fix this error and what am I doing wrong?
